Upgrade from Cassandra version 2.1.11 to 4.0.13, package not found
I upgrades Cassandra version from 2.1.11 to 4.0.13, and i see below package has been removed from the Cassandra version 2.2 onwards,
[ERROR] */BloomFilterLookup.java:[132,27] package Murmur3BloomFilter does not exist
v2.1: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils
v2.2: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/cassandra-2.2/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils
Am not able to find the alternative package to use at place of Murmur3BloomFilter. Also didn't find any migration document for upgrading from v2.1 to v4.0.
Could someone help me on this ?

Was removed in 18d8f26ddd556d6b689a7460053c1518a86d7288

Comment to commit: "Evaluate MurmurHash of Token once per query
patch by branimir; reviewed by benedict for CASSANDRA-7096"

Looks like it was replaced by BloomFilter

@talex i tried with BloomFilter but it didn't work

Thanks for posting on Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

am new to java, when i tried to create object of BloomFilter class then its not accessible, BloomFilter abc= new BloomFilter(4, new OffHeapBitSet(40000000)); error is "The constructor BloomFilter(int, IBitSet) is not visible" how do i create the object of BloomFilter ?

It is not possible to upgrade Cassandra 2.1 to 4.0 directly. It is not a supported operation because each major version of Cassandra is only backward-compatible with one major version.
Each major version comes with significant changes to components and functionality that are only compatible with the previous major version including SSTable formats, native protocol versions, drivers and schema/gossip.
You will need to perform interim upgrades to get to the target major version. It is important to note that C* 2.1.11 was released in 2015 and is an extremely old version of Cassandra. You will need to upgrade to C* 2.1.22 which is the last version of C* 2.1 (released in 2020).
In your case, the supported and recommended upgrade path is: upgrade to C* 2.1.latest => C* 3.11.latest => C* 4.0.latest.
The high-level steps are:

Perform the upgrade steps from C* 2.1.11 to latest in C* 2.1 NEWS.txt.
Perform a minor upgrade to the latest version of C* 2.1 (C* 2.1.22 at the time of writing).
WARNING - C* 2.1 uses CQL native protocol v3. C* 3.x uses native protocol v4 so you will need to refactor your application to use an updated driver that supports protocol v4.
Perform the upgrade steps from C* 3.0 to C* 3.11.16 in C* 3.11 NEWS.txt.
Upgrade to the latest version of C* 3.11 (C* 3.11.17).
Perform the upgrade steps from C* 4.0 to C* 4.0.13 in C* 4.0 NEWS.txt.

It is important to note that APIs have changed between major versions and will require you to refactor your application. Cheers!

Thanks for your response, after upgrade to 4.0 version, i see only one error in my project i.e. murmur3BloomFilter, let me know if you have any idea to create an object of a class which is having private constructor and i want to access that constructor only ...
